# How to refresh datagrid in vb.net after update

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2010

This is a part of module(Update book's Details) in Library Management System. But when I change the details and click the update button, the updated data successfully stored in Database, but the updated data isn't refresh in the datagrid simultaneously.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.DataTable

Public Class frmBooksUpdate

    Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LMS_DB.accdb")
    Dim con As OleDbConnection
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection = ds.Tables
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource()

    Private Sub Refreshdata()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [BookID], [Title], [Author], [Publisher], [Category], [Price], [ISBN] FROM tblBooks", myConnection)
        da.Fill(ds, "tblBooks")
        Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view1
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
        DataGridView1.Refresh()

    End Sub
    Private Sub frmBookSearch_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Refreshdata()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

        txtBookID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)
        txtTitle.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
        txtAuthor.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)
        txtPublisher.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3)
        txtCategory.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4)
        txtPrice.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5)
        txtISBN.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(6)

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "UPDATE [tblBooks] SET [Title] = '" & txtTitle.Text & "' , [Author] = '" & txtAuthor.Text & "', [Publisher] = '" & txtPublisher.Text & "', [Category] = '" & txtCategory.Text & "', [Price] = '" & txtPrice.Text & "', [ISBN] = '" & txtISBN.Text & "' WHERE [BookID] = " & txtBookID.Text & ""

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()

            MessageBox.Show("The Book Updated", "Book Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)


            txtAuthor.Clear()
            txtBookID.Clear()
            txtCategory.Clear()
            txtISBN.Clear()
            txtPrice.Clear()
            txtPublisher.Clear()
            txtTitle.Clear()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Just call `Refreshdata` function after `MessageBox.Show("The Book Updated", "Book Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)` line in `btnUpdate_Click`
`

Comment: I inserted this function. But the old data also is shown the datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `RefreshData()` inside your update event........

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "UPDATE [tblBooks] SET [Title] = '" & txtTitle.Text & "' , [Author] = '" & txtAuthor.Text & "', [Publisher] = '" & txtPublisher.Text & "', [Category] = '" & txtCategory.Text & "', [Price] = '" & txtPrice.Text & "', [ISBN] = '" & txtISBN.Text & "' WHERE [BookID] = " & txtBookID.Text & ""

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("The Book Updated", "Book Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)


        txtAuthor.Clear()
        txtBookID.Clear()
        txtCategory.Clear()
        txtISBN.Clear()
        txtPrice.Clear()
        txtPublisher.Clear()
        txtTitle.Clear()

        RefreshData()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: There is an error "Error that 'DataBind' is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'

Comment: @SanthanakumaranSakthybaalan sorry for that. i thought you're using webforms... please see my edit anyway for the complete answer

Comment: Sorry, I used your code but the datagridview shows the old record also.

Form_Load : https://flic.kr/p/C64cfc

Updated After : https://flic.kr/p/Cb2GFf

Answer (score 0):

Add RefreshData() inside your btnUpdate_Click, right after the `MsgBox.Show`